# Mac Book Pro 2013 battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I got a new Mac Book Pro, (not retina) and the battery indicator is only showing 98%.

Is this something of concern?

I have found this:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4228218?start=0&tstart=0

> Sit and watch it constantly, this will take some hours, it will charge to 100% from time to time, usually just a little less (like 98, or 96) in order to protect the battery from overcharging.

But I was looking for something official, but couldn't find it.
And the official "battery link" doesn't say anything about this:

http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found "official" information on this, both my 2007 Macbook and my 2011 Macbook Pro will rarely show a 100% charge, I assume it's normal behaviour.

Take into account that the battery measurement is only an estimate so even if it shows 100% it does not mean that the battery has reached *exactly* full charge.